# How to specify the label name of the last elements of a tree in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using D3.js and trying to display some data in the form of a tree with nodes.

The labels work fine for the root and the first layer of children. But the last layer of children contain data where each one is a single object and I want to display the country name in that object.

Data is originally in the form of an array so I filter them to form the necessary structure to be visualised in D3.js. `agroforestry` stores the data used for making the visualisations.

```
  const agroforestry = {
    name: "Intiative 2020",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Agroforestry",
        children: [],
      },
      {
        name: "No Agroforestry",
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  };

  data.forEach((d) =>
    d.agroforestry === 1
      ? agroforestry.children[0].children.push(d)
      : agroforestry.children[1].children.push(d)
  );
```

Example object inside `agroforestry.children[1].children`:

```
  const example = {
    agroforestry: 0,
    avoided_degradation_and_deforestation: 1,
    country: "Chile",
    descriptions:
      "In Chile's Patagonia region, grasslands were severely degraded after years of uncontrolled sheep and cattle grazing",
    funding: 0,
    geolocation: "(-31.7613365, -71.3187697)",
    investment_type: "Private",
    latitude: -31.7613365,
    locations: "Patagonia",
    longitude: -71.3187697,
    low_carbon_agriculture: 0,
    partner_organization: "[]",
    partner_organization_urls: "[]",
    reforestation: 0,
    silvopasture: 0,
    sustainably_managed_grasslands: 1,
    titles: "Ecological restoration chacabuco valley",
    urls:
      "https://initiative20x20.org/restoration-projects/ecological-restoration-chacabuco-valley",
  };
```

Label from the parent is visible with `.text((node) => node.data.name)` and set it as the label.

```
    svg
      .selectAll(".label")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .join("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .text((node) => node.data.name)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-size", 14)
      .attr("x", (node) => node.y)
      .attr("y", (node) => node.x - 10);
```

[image]

Label from the parent is not visible but the country label is(need to edit the styling but it works) when I choose country `.text((node) => node.data.country)`.

```
    svg
      .selectAll(".label")
      .data(root.descendants())
      .join("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .text((node) => node.data.country)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-size", 14)
      .attr("x", (node) => node.y)
      .attr("y", (node) => node.x - 10);
```

[image]

**So how do I keep the label of the parent and first layer of children as `node.data.name` while also keeping the label of the last layer of children as `node.data.country`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mutually exclusive cases:

- Does the node have children? => `data.name`
- Otherwhise, the node is a leaf node => `data.country`

So the real question is **how can we check that the current node is (not) a leaf node**?

To this end, we can use [d3-hierarchy's provided methods on nodes](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-hierarchy). (Check out the good examples there as well.) One example shows us the `node.children` property.

If it's set, then the node has children (so it is not a leaf node), and we can use it like this in our own code:

```
svg                               // node          // leaf
  .text((node) => node.children ? node.data.name : node.data.country)
```